# GeoJSON data disappears when using Marker cluster plugin

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, web-mapping

Here is the code I used to display my GeoJSON data on a leaflet map using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Through the following code I wanted to load my point data on the map and form clusters of it using Marker Cluster plugin.

I could easily display my spatial data on my map but I am unable to create marker clusters. To display my spatial data I used fetch function because `$.getJson` did not seem to work. When I added the code for marker cluster my data disappeared.

Can anyone please help me understand the cause of this error?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Inline Map</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <style>
          #map {
            top: 600%;
            left: 5%;
            position: right;
            width: 1300px;
            height: 600px;
            border: 6px solid #0B5345;
            border-radius: 15px;
          }
        </style>

        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
          integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
          crossorigin=""
        />
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
          href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/MarkerCluster.css"
        />
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
          href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/MarkerCluster.Default.css"
        />
        <script
          type="text/javascript"
          src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"
        ></script>
        <script
          type="text/javascript"
          src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/leaflet.markercluster.js"
        ></script>

        <script
          src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
          integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
          crossorigin=""
        ></script>
      </head>

      <body>
        //To display the map
        <div id="map"></div>

        // Map Code 
        <script>
          // Create variable to hold map element, give initial settings to map
          var map = L.map("map", { center: [18.521428, 73.8544541], zoom: 14 });

          // Add OpenStreetMap tile layer to map element
          L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
            attribution:
              '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
          }).addTo(map);

          // Create an Empty Popup
          var popup = L.popup();

          // Write function to set Properties of the Popup
          function onMapClick(e) {
            popup
              .setLatLng(e.latlng)
              .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
              .openOn(map);
          }

          // Listen for a click event on the Map element
          map.on("click", onMapClick);
           //fetching geojson data from given URL 
          fetch(
            "https://cdn.glitch.com/3b46ae34-c2e2-48fe-b99c-5bb9412d0e1a%2Fpmpml_surgeon_busstop.geojson?v=1589713237973"
          )
            .then(function(response) {
              return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(data) {
              var clusters = L.markerClusterGroup();
              var incidents = L.geoJson(data, {
                pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                  var marker = L.marker(latlng);
                  marker.bindPopup(
                    "bus stop name:" +
                      feature.properties["stop_name"] +
                      "<br>stop code:" +
                      feature.properties["stop_code"] +
                      "<br>Latitude:" +
                      feature.properties["stop_lat"] +
                      "<br>Longitude:" +
                      feature.properties["stop_lon"]  );
                  return marker;
                },
                onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
                  layer.addTo(clusters);
                }
              });
              map.addLayer(clusters);
            });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to GISSE! One humble question to you: Why don't you add some more details to the question and clarify the problem beforehand? There is no need to add them as comments. This way, no one will delete or flag your question and every body can take a chance on solving your problem immediately.

Comment: "Wall of code" questions (just code, without environment, problem statement, or error description) attract downvotes. Please [Edit] the question to place the comment words in your Question (but leave out the helpme and gratefulness, and also the request).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions root676 and Vince

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are adding GeoJSON layers to the marker cluster group layer, but as the name `L.markerClusterGroup` itself tells, this group layer is intended for markers, not layers.

Just leave out `onEachFeature` option and instead add markers to `clusters` in the `pointToLayer` option processing function:

```
var clusters = L.markerClusterGroup();
var incidents = L.geoJson(data, {
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    var marker = L.marker(latlng);
    marker.bindPopup(
      "bus stop name:" +
        feature.properties["stop_name"] +
        "<br>stop code:" +
        feature.properties["stop_code"] +
        "<br>Latitude:" +
        feature.properties["stop_lat"] +
        "<br>Longitude:" +
        feature.properties["stop_lon"]);
    marker.addTo(clusters);
    return marker;
  }
});
map.addLayer(clusters);
```

Comment: I did what you said ..but still the same output ... my data is still not getting displayed

Comment: Are you sure your GeoJSON url works? When I try it, I get "Not Found" message.

Comment: Yes it works, I checked twice.

Comment: When I try it in a browser, I get "Not Found" message.